# How can I arrange divs like in image?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to do something like this [image]

I am using bootstrap 4 and got this [image: my crap]

With the following code:

```
<div class="col-2 row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-6">
    {{cart.quantity}}
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 text-left">
    <div class="col-12">
      +
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
      -
    </div>
  </div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: With something this specific you probably don't want to involve Bootstrap's grid system classes. Make your own class, so that you can specify the object shape and behavior down to the pixels.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure Bootstrap has some Boostrapey component that does that, so that you don't have to create your own, like this Bootstrap 4.2 custom Range component https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#range

Answer (score 0):

You will need to actually make the divs smaller or assign a icon class. Your backgroud and radius is spreading over the full width of the div `<div class="col-12">+</div>`